# How to start firefox on Ubuntu touch using the terminal

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, firefox

I need for my work to run firefox on my Aquaris M10 tablet using the terminal.

I already tried this:

- "Unlock" the tablet (with android-gadget-service enable writable) I used apt-get install firefox to install firefox, but when I tried to start the app with /usr/bin/firefox I have this error "Cannot open display" / "Error no display specified" (I tried to change with DISPLAY:=0 and other found on SO)
- This tutorial http://mutse.github.io/2015/11/08/howto-launch-desktop-apps-on-utouch/ , it works during 0.000001 sec then close: "cross-device link problem" & "fail to complie keymap"
- and start the installed app from Ubuntu touch /custom/click/com.ubuntu.puritine/0.11/libertine-data/libertine-container/puritine/rootsf/usr/lib/firefox/firefox , still not working

Thanks you.

Comment: Can you further describe your scenario? Are you running firefox from a terminal to collect logs, or something else? If you're using the Desktop Applications scope with libertine, you could create a custom .desktop file with the correct command line flags.